# Keyboard is showing on first tap for a UITextField.inputView = UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uipickerview, inputview

I couldn't find nothing respect to Swift about this matter.

I'm configuring a `UIPickerView` as `inputView` for a `UITextField`.

Everything is working fine, but when I tap on this specific `UITextField` at the fisrt time, the keyboard is showing, not the `UIPickerView`, if I click on it again, the `UIPickerView` is showed.

Anyone know what am I doing wrong?

See some parts of my code.

```
@IBAction func textFieldEditingMot(sender: UITextField) {

    let motivoPicker: UIPickerView = UIPickerView()

    motivos = ["Pedido de demissão","Dispensa sem justa causa","Dispensa com justa causa", "Término do contrato de experiência"]

    motivoPicker.delegate = self
    motivoPicker.dataSource = self
    motivoTextField.inputView = motivoPicker

}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    return motivos.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{
    motivoTextField.text = motivos[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{
    return motivos[row]
}
```

Comment: Do you have the UITextFieldDelegate set?

Comment: I'm new on this, can you explain how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you are setting your UITextFieldDelegate, and then I would also move all of this:

```
let motivoPicker: UIPickerView = UIPickerView()

motivos = ["Pedido de demissão","Dispensa sem justa causa","Dispensa com justa causa", "Término do contrato de experiência"]

motivoPicker.delegate = self
motivoPicker.dataSource = self
motivoTextField.inputView = motivoPicker
```

to viewDidLoad

Comment: Thats't IT! I was putting this inside the `IBAction`, really thanks for your help, it's working perfectly.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad I could be some help!  :)